# Yom Kippur - nicotine patch

Tags: halacha, medicine, fast-days, yom-kippur, tobacco-cig-smoking

Is there any problem with wearing a nicotine patch on Yom Kippur or any other fast day? (sources please)

Comment: On Yom Kippur it can be an issur hotzaah if there’s no eruv. (Carrying in a public domain)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/atr/a/?category=Yom+Kippur%2C+wearing+nicotine+patch) you may, because its not eating

(source: ["Teshuvot V'Hanhagot" by R' M. Sternbuch, II 290](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=253&hilite=)).

Comment: What?!? I mean, yes, [Aish says that there](http://www.aish.com/atr/a/?category=Yom+Kippur%2C+wearing+nicotine+patch), but [their source, _Rav_ Sternbuch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=253&hilite=), seems to be saying it's forbidden on _YK_! (Unless maybe I'm reading him wrong?)

Comment: @msh210: he's talking about "feeding through the veins" - i.e., intravenous nourishment. That's not necessarily the same thing as nicotine, which is not normally taken into the body as food.

Comment: @Alex, I'll certainly grant it's not the strongest possible support for forbidding a nicotine patch, but if it's support for anything, it's for forbidding, no?

Comment: I do not see where in the Teshuva Rabbi Sternbuch says that you may.

Comment: @Alex: On the other hand, the heter for smoking on Yom Tov is that it is food.

Comment: @Menachem: not really. It's that it's "ochel nefesh," but that includes other things that are commonly used for bodily comfort, like bathing.

Comment: @msh210: if I'm understanding R. Sternbuch correctly, his objection to intravenous feeding is that even though it's not "eating," it interferes with the "affliction" one should feel by abstaining from food (צער מניעת אכילה). Well, since the nicotine patch is not replacing food, then that consideration shouldn't apply; the only concern would be whether taking substances into the body non-orally is considered "eating," and having established that it is not, then there's no reason left to prohibit it.

Comment: @Alex: Do you have a source where I can get some more information about the definition of "ochel nefesh"?

Comment: @Alex, ah, yes, that makes sense. Thank you!